# Como selecionar o objeto inteiro, Lambda C#

Tags: c#, linq, expressões-lambda

Tenho uma dificuldade aqui nesta lambda, gostaria de saber como eu seleciono o objeto inteiro, sem ter que especificar todos as propriedades dele.

Como se fosse um: SELECT * FROM AlgumaCoisa

Sem ter que especificar como: SELECT ID, BLA, BLE FROM AlgumaCoisa

Já tenho um pedaço de como eu quero:

```
var query = this.clientDbContext.Printers
                .Where(p => p.PlaceId == placeId);

        if (!getRemoved)
            query = query.Where(where => where.WasRemoved == false);

        if (onlyWithCounters)
            query = query
                .Join(this.systemDbContext.PrinterCounter, printer => printer.PrinterId, pc => pc.PrinterId, (printer, pc) => new { Printer = printer })
                .Select(select => select.Printer);
```

Não sei se assim é a forma correta de fazer, gostaria que os mais experientes me ajudassem :)

Pensei que nessa parte que fiz:

```
(printer, pc) => new { Printer = printer })
```

Isso fosse resolver

```
(printer, pc) => printer)
```

Para esclarecer, eu quero simular com isso:

```
.Join(this.systemDbContext.PrinterCounter, printer => printer.PrinterId, pc => pc.PrinterId, (printer, pc) => new { Printer = printer })
                .Select(select => select.Printer);
```

Isso:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [*banco do cliente*].[dbo].[Printers] AS printer 
JOIN [*banco principal*].[dbo].PrinterCounter AS cp ON printer.PrinterId = cp.PrinterId
```

Comment: Porque está usando Join?

Comment: Porque eu quero selecionar apenas Printers que tem contadores na tabela PrinterCounter.

Comment: Você quer trazer Printer, que tenha informações em PrinterCounter? se sim poste os dois models e se possivel as duas tabelas!

Comment: Infelizmente não posso mostrar além disso :/

Comment: Se não pode colocar nem a relação?

Comment: Eu precisa saber se é 1 para N? relação não tem problema você postar!

Comment: A relação é 1 pra 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se a sua relação for **1 para 1** entre `Printers` e `PrinterCounter` faça assim:

***Classes:***

```
public class Printer
{
    public int PrinterId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual PrinterCounter PrinterCounter { get; set; }
}

public class PrinterCounter
{
    public int PrinterId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }    
    public virtual Printer Printer { get; set; }
}
```

***Codigo:***

```
using (MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext())
{
    var result = db.Printers
             .Where(c => c.PrinterCounter != null)
             .ToList();
}
```

***SQL*** gerada por essa expressão:

```
SELECT
    [Extent1].[PrinterId] AS [PrinterId],
    [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name]
    FROM  [dbo].[Printer] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[PrinterCounter] AS [Extent2] 
            ON [Extent1].[PrinterId] = [Extent2].[PrinterId]
    WHERE 1 = 1
```

Comment: Exatamente o que eu precisava, muito obrigado!

Comment: @VictorHugoSchmidt se for a resposta aceite por favor

Answer (score 3):

Tu pode escrever o select no final da expressão, como o LINQ mencionou:

```
query.Join(this.systemDbContext.PrinterCounter, printer => printer.PrinterId, pc => pc.PrinterId, (printer, pc) => new { Printer = printer })
                .Select(select => select);
```

Ou depende do que tu precisa, pra selecionar uma lista:

```
query.Join(this.systemDbContext.PrinterCounter, printer => printer.PrinterId, pc => pc.PrinterId, (printer, pc) => new { Printer = printer }).ToList();
```

Ou selecionar apenas um:

```
query.Join(this.systemDbContext.PrinterCounter, printer => printer.PrinterId, pc => pc.PrinterId, (printer, pc) => new { Printer = printer }).First() / FirstOrDefault() / Single() / SingleOrDefault()...
```

Comment: Nenhum deles será possível, pois não existe transformação de um objeto anônimo para IQueryable.

Comment: Quando dou um ToList(), ele fala que o valor não pode ser nulo.